# XSLT: If check parameter value

Tags: xslt

Following code in xslt (I've cut out the irrelevant parts, get-textblock is a lot longer and has a lot of parameters which are all passed correctly):

```
<xsl:template name="get-textblock">
        <xsl:param name="style"/>

        <xsl:element name="Border">         
            <xsl:if test="$style='{StaticResource LabelText}'" >
                <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B596E</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>              
        </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

The style parameter can be either '{StaticResource LabelText}' or '{StaticResource ValueText}' and the background of the border depends on that value.

This if structure fails however, it always draws the FF3B5940 border in my output.xaml file.
I call the template like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="get-textblock">
    <xsl:with-param name="style">{StaticResource LabelText}</xsl:with-param>                    
</xsl:call-template>
```

Anyone sees what might be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line:

```
<xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>
```

is not protected by a conditional check, so it will always execute.

Use this:

```
<xsl:if test="$style='{StaticResource LabelText}'">
    <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B596E</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not($style='{StaticResource LabelText}')">
    <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Or `xsl:choose`

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$style='{StaticResource LabelText}'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B596E</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: ... Oh God, you can't believe how stupid I feel that I looked over such a triviality :D Thanks. (give me 6 minutes to accept this answer :p)

Comment: @Matthias - If you're feeling evil, just output this: `<Border Background="{concat(substring('#FF3B596E', 1 div ($style='{StaticResource LabelText}')), substring('#FF3B5940', 1 div not($style='{StaticResource LabelText}')))}"/>`

Answer (score 4):

If you use `<xsl:attribute/>` multiple times in the one element context, only last one will be applied to result element.

You can separate `<xsl:attribute/>` instructions using `<xsl:choose/>` or define one `<xsl:attribute/>` before `<xsl:if/>` -- it will be used by default:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$style='{StaticResource LabelText}'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B596E</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

or

```
        <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B5940</xsl:attribute>  
        <xsl:if test="$style='{StaticResource LabelText}'" >
            <xsl:attribute name="Background">#FF3B596E</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template name="get-textblock">
   <xsl:param name="style"/>   
   <Border Background="{if ($style='{StaticResource LabelText}') 
                        then '#FF3B596E' 
                        else '#FF3B5940'}"/>         

</xsl:template>
```